# How to find colours on all pages of a Figma design

Tags: figma

I have a Figma design... time to turn it into code.

The first thing I'll do is break sections up into components and I'll use SCSS/SASS/CSS to create colour variables.

Accordingly it would be helpful to have a list of all colours used throughout the entire design, not on a page by page basis.

The same with fonts, font sizes/styles etc.

Once I have those items I will then just be left to create components which probably needs to be done by hand.